# How to make views in android

Tags: android

actually i want to ask about some frontend views in android. I dont want you to write code for me. I just need your valuable suggestions

1) A line on which when we wipe left or right a bubble appears on line and its value increase or decrease respectively or line also show progress

[image]

2) A line with few dots on it when we click on specific dot. The dot become focus able and larger

[image]

Comment: Can't you use a library? Something like [this](https://mindorks.com/android/store/Progress-Indicators/kofigyan/stateprogressbar)

Comment: ok but what about first one?

Comment: I couldn't find the exact thing but here's something similar [percentageBar](https://mindorks.com/android/store/Progress-Indicators/daimajia/numberprogressbar). [This](https://mindorks.com/android/store/Progress-Indicators/tibolte/elasticdownload) is kinda similar too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Request: [this](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar) or [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6434)

2nd Request: [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6931) or [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6448) or [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4883)

Hope this helps...